# Change sorting order to AaBbCcDd

Tags: sorting, alphabetical, lexicographic, alphabetical-sort, alphabetic

I have several files in a directory in my unix system that I need to sort. The problem I'm having is that when using the sort -f command it sorts in the order a A b B c C etc. ls does the same ordering. Is there a way I can make it sort with the uppercase letter coming first? i.e. sort in the order A a B b C c ...

Answer (score 0):

With multiple passes through the sort command I think this is what you want:

```
ls | sort -f -r | sort
```